# Checking for Invalid Key

Tags: python

I have a while loop:

```
while parent != None:
     pathList.append(parentMap[parent])
     parent = parentMap[parent]
```

What I want to do with this list is simply add the parent value (already determined in other parts of the code) of a parent value to a list until I've reached the top of a tree and there are no more parents remaining. The while loop operates under the idea that once parentMap[parent] is provided with an invalid [parent] key, it will be assigned the value of "None" and the loop will terminate. This doesn't happen. Instead, once I get to the topmost key, (5, 5), the program throws an error stating "invalid key." Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, as others have also pointed out, is in the fact that a `dict` doesn't return `None` if a key isn't found but instead raises a `KeyError` exception ([as seen in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict)).

To overcome this you could use `defaultdict` from `collections` and set `None` to be the default value for that dict. I recommend you read the [classes documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

In this case, instead of initializing your `dict` as `parentMap = dict(some_initializer)` or `parentMap = {}` you could use `parentMap = defaultdict(lambda: None, some_initializer)` or `parentMap = defaultdict(lambda: None, {})` and missing keys will return `None` rather than raising `KeyError` exceptions.

In an unrelated issue, `None` is a singleton, It's better to check if an `item is not None` rather than using `!=`. It generates clearer code, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `get` method to return a default value if the key is not found in the map:

```
while parent is not None:
    pathList.append(parentMap[parent])
    parent = parentMap.get(parent, None) # returns None if key is not found
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while parent != None:
      try:
           pathList.append(parentMap[parent])
           parent = parentMap[parent]
      except KeyError:
           parent = None
```

should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Well the reason you get an error stating `invalid key` is because presumably you're not assigning `parentMap[parent]` of the top parent to `None`, you're just not putting it in the map. Since it's not in the map, the default behavior is to throw an `invalid key` error.

Is that what you're doing?

Edit: To remedy, use `parentMap.get(parent, None)`

Comment: Yes (I thought it wouldn't throw an error but simply assign a value of None), but I'm not sure how to ameliorate the situation. If I initialize the parent of the uppermost value to be None, then it tries to map None onto the list and things go haywire again...

Comment: Either Joran or John's methods are fine for fixing it. I personally would go with John's because I was taught that avoiding try/except was good practice, but either should work.

Comment: Also note that John's solution uses `is not None` instead of `!= None`, which is also better style.